# How to merge vertically several csv files in Python?

Tags: python, csv, merge

I need to merge vertically the data from several CSV spreadsheets in Python. Their structure is identical, I just need to put one table's data on top of the following because they are the months on an annual survey. I tried several methods I found googling but I can't find a way to do something as simple as:

```
import csv

spreadsheets1 = open('0113_RE_fscom.csv','r')
spreadsheets2 = open('0213_RE_fscom.csv','r')
spreadsheets = spreadsheets1 + spreadsheets2

with spreadsheet as csvfile:
   sales = csv.reader(csvfile)
   for row in sales:
      print row
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you simply forgot to iterate over files. Try this code:

```
import csv

spreadsheet_filenames = [
    '0113_RE_fscom.csv',
    '0213_RE_fscom.csv',
]

for filename in spreadsheet_filenames:
    with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
        sales = csv.reader(csvfile)
        for row in sales:
            print row
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this:

```
import csv
from itertools import izip

with open('0113_RE_fscom.csv', 'r') as f1, open('0113_RE_fscom.csv', 'r') as f2:
   csv1 = csv.reader(f1, delimiter=',')
   csv2 = csv.reader(f2, delimiter=',')
   for line1, line2 in izip(csv1, csv2):
      print line1 + line2
```

Answer (score 0):

This is quite simple with pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
f1 = pd.read_csv('0113_RE_fscom.csv', header=None)
f2 = pd.read_csv('0213_RE_fscom.csv', header=None)
merged = pd.concat(f1, f2)
merged.to_csv('merged.csv', index=None, header=None)
```

Remove `header=None` if your files actually do have a header.